# Evenly spaced points in a line between two n-dimensional points using Python

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra

I need to evenly space X points in a line between two N-dimensional points. I want to create a Python function that gets both points and X as input and returns the coordinates of the X points.

```py
get_points(point_a=(1, 1), point_b=(2, 2), x=10)
>>> [(x0, y0), (x1, y1), ..., (x8, y8), (x9, y9)]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: First you should understand the math. The beginning of this (the representation of a line segment with vectors) could help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment#In_real_or_complex_vector_spaces

Comment: You can treat each dimension separately and put equally spaced points between them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `x` inner points (so the first one and the last one don't coincide with `a` and `b`), then segment is divided to `(x+1)` subintervals:

```
xstep = (b[0]-a[0]) / (x+1)
ystep = (b[1]-a[1]) / (x+1)
result = [(a[0] + xstep*i, a[1] + ystep*i) for i in range(1, x+1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're living in `numpy` land:

```
alpha = np.linspace(0,1,n)
interpolants = np.outer(x1, alpha) + np.outer(x2, 1-alpha)
```